# How to count the number of distinct multiline index in pandas, only by one of the indices components

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:
[Input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6bOC.png)

I want to find the contribution of each category to the Price(USD) column by day. So far I've tried aggregating by Timestamp and Category, with the sum of Price(USD):

```
df3 = df.groupby(["Timestamp", "Category"]).sum()
```

Obtaining the following dataset:

[Dataset grouped by Timestamp and Category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvCxF.png)

After this point, I haven't been able to  apply a function to each row to divide each Price(USD) by the sum of all different categories in each day and create a new column with these values.

Ideally, a new column "Percentage" would contain :

> Percentage

1. 0.3/(0.3+0.2+0.1)
2. 0.2/(0.3+0.2+0.1)
3. 0.1/(0.3+0.2+0.1)

With the same pattern for the rest of the dataframe.

Thank you

Comment: post the data inline to make it easier to reproduce and validate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you need

```
>>> df.groupby(["Timestamp", "Category"]).sum() / df.groupby(["Timestamp"]).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

here is another way about it

```
df.groupby(['Timestamp','Category'])['price'].transform(sum) /  df.groupby(['Timestamp'])['price'].transform(sum)
```